# Boolean difference in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I have two matrix (A, B) and I want to calculate the element-by-element differences. Then, I want to give me 0 for non-matching elements and give me 1 otherwise (for matched elements or the elements which their difference is 0). Is there any function in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if elements of matrices are identical using `==`.

```
A = [1 2 3];
B = [1 0 3];
C = A == B;   % gives C = [1 0 1]
```

Comment: @sholezer: but the output is not 0 and 1 !! I need a function that its output be just 0 (for the non-matched elements) and 1 (for the matched elements)